# Condição de finalização de programa em C!

Tags: c, lógica

Tenho um programa em C onde a saída devera ser a media dos números digitados e quantos desses valores que foram digitados são maiores que a media.

o programa recebe até 100 valores F, onde F é um valor positivo entre 0 e 5000 e para de receber valores quando eu digito -1.

estou com problemas para finalizar o programa, ele não finaliza quando eu digito -1, ele só finaliza apos eu digitar dois números negativos.

**código:**

```
#include<stdio.h>


int contaMaiores(double vetor[], int indiceMax, double media){

  int c = 0;          // controle de indice vetor
  int m = 0;          // contador de medias

  for (c = 0; c < indiceMax; c++) {

    if (vetor[c] > media) {

      m = m + 1;

    } // fim do if

  } // fim do for

  return(m);

} // fim do contaMaiores


int main() {

  double vetor [100];                // vetor para armazenar numeros
  int contN = 0;                     // contador para numeros
  double soma = 0;
  double n;
  double media;
  int maiores;


  scanf("%lf\n", &n);

  // (1 <= N <= 100)
  // (0 <= F <= 5000)
  while (contN < 100 && n >= 0.0 && n <= 5000.0) {

    vetor[contN] = n;

    contN = contN + 1;

    soma = soma + n;

    scanf("%lf\n", &n);

  } // fim do while

  media = (soma/contN);

  maiores = contaMaiores(vetor, contN, media);

  printf("%lf\n", media);
  printf("%d\n", maiores);

  return 0;

} // fim do main
```

Answer (score 4):

Cara, é uma boa, quando pedir entrada de dados em uma estrutura de repetição, vc usar um `fflush(stdin)`, para limpar o buffer, sem levar em consideração esses '\n' no `scanf`.

```
while (contN < 100 && n >= 0.0) {

    if(n <= 5000.0){
     vetor[contN] = n;

     contN = contN + 1;

     soma = soma + n;

     fflush(stdin);
     scanf("%lf", &n);

    } //Se ele inserir 6.000, não é condição de parada (-1), apenas um valor inválido.

} // fim do while
```

Answer (score 3):

Você está fazendo a leitura incorreta. Remova o caractere '\n' de seus scanfs e o bug sairá.